# Internal authentication to Cassandra DB using C# driver

Tags: c#-4.0, cassandra

I am trying to Connect to Cassandra by mentioning the userName, Password and clusterName.But I am not able to do that. Kindly help me to this consent.

```
Cluster  cluster = Cluster.Builder().WithCredentials(username,     
    password).AddContactPoint("localhost").Build();
```

I tried this but its not working for what i required

Comment: I have cross checked the Cassandra.yaml file . I have configured the authentication type to Password Authentication. That was the thing missing but now i have done that and listen_address needs to be localhost as of now, for my application requirement . Still Its not working.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is syntactically correct (and matches code that I use).

Double-check your `cassandra.yaml` file for the `listen_address` parameter.  This is the hostname/ip that you should be using in your `Cluster.Builder` statement.  If your `listen_address` is anything other than "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" then your code won't work as-is.

If that's not it, check to make sure that you can communicate on port 9042.  One technique that I use is defining my connections in DataStax's [DevCenter](http://www.datastax.com/what-we-offer/products-services/devcenter), so that I can test them out first.

[image]

Here you can easily use your username, password, and hostname to double-check (and test) your connection properties.  Give that a try, and see if you can connect from DevCenter using the same credentials.

Comment: Is there any change required in cassandra.yaml other than authorization and authenticater

Comment: No, as long as you followed the instructions from here: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/webhelp/index.html#cassandra/security/security_config_native_authenticate_t.html then you should be good.  And of course, you should be authenticating as your new user, and not "cassandra."

Comment: password authentication skipped . some nodes where not ready..  After changing cassandra.yaml and replication factor then its showing above error on server startup and other problem is <client startup string> -u cassandra -p cassandra   for this command its telling 'u' as unidentified command